# transforming String and getting the Specified Value Java (Android)

Tags: java, android

I am a new in Android development and I want to write a function which I have  written for `IOS` in swift, so if anybody can help me with this then it will be great :

I want to convert a String from

`String1 = "Guardians Of the Galaxy(G.T.G)"`

into

`String2 = "GTG"`

All I want to is to get the value which is inside the brackets and remove the `.` from it and also if there's any  space within them

here's  how I do it in Swift maybe it'll help to understand

if the `spaceLessFullForm = "Catch Me if You Can"`

```
let SpaceLessFullForm = Fullform.condensedWhitespace
let delimiters: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "()")
var splitString: [AnyObject] = SpaceLessFullForm.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(delimiters)
let substring: String = splitString[1] as! String
print(substring)
let dotLessString = substring.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "")
let upperCaseFirstCharcters = dotLessString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
```

then my  `upperCaseFirstCharcters = "CMIUC"`

Comment: what is problem tho?

Comment: want to extract the text which is inside the bracket of any string @vrundpurohit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way..

```
String kek = "Guardians Of the Galaxy(G.T .G . V)";
int fInd = kek.indexOf("(") + 1;
int lInd = kek.indexOf(")");
String kek1 = kek.substring(fInd, lInd);
String kek2 = kek1.replace(".", "").replace(" ", "");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), kek2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
```

Result will be : **GTGV**

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string into parts.

```
String string = "Guardians Of the Galaxy(G.T.G)";
String[] parts = string.split("(");
```

Then just remove the characters that you dont need.

```
String neededString = parts[1].replace(".", "").replace(")", "");
```

This is sample, which might helps you to get the answer. Not tested

Answer (score 1):

Based on your usecase the simple solution would be to find the indexes of the brackets, take a substring and then replace the dots with nothing. If one of the brackets has an index of -1 you can find the position of each space an take the char after the space. Please note this code will compile but is a minimalistic example. It will fail if you have for instance 2 consecutive spaces, a space at the end of the text, or if you're missing one of the brackets.

```
public class Parser
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "Guardians Of the Galaxy (G.T.G)";
        String test2 = "Catch Me if You Can";
        String thisWillFail = "This will fail ";

        System.out.println(parseItem(test));
        System.out.println(parseItem(test2));
    }

    public static String parseItem(String item)
    {
        String result = "";
        int indexStart = item.indexOf("(") + 1;
        int indexEnd = item.indexOf(")");

        if(indexStart != -1 && indexEnd != -1) 
        {       
            String subString = item.substring(indexStart, indexEnd);
            result = subString.replace(".", "");
        }
        else
        {
            result += item.charAt(0);
            while(item.contains(" "))
            {
                int nextSpace = item.indexOf(" ");
                result += item.charAt(nextSpace + 1);
                item = item.substring(nextSpace + 1);
            }
        }
        return result.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code will help you to extract the text in java:

```
    String str1 = "Guardians Of the Galaxy(G.T.G)";
    String str2 = "";
    boolean flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        if(str1.charAt(i) == '(') {
            flag = true;
            continue;
        } else if(str1.charAt(i) == ')') {
            break;
        }
        if(flag) {
            if(str1.charAt(i) != '.' && str1.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                str2 += str1.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    Log.i("str2", str2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String s = "Guardians Of the Galaxy(G.T.G)";
System.out.print(s.substring(s.indexOf('(')+1, s.indexOf(')')).replaceAll("\\.", "").replaceAll(" ", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this ::

```
   String str1 = "Guardians Of the Galaxy(G.T.G)";
        String str2 = str1.substring(str1.indexOf("(")+1,str1.indexOf(")")).replace(".","");
```